# Gem 'byebug' not being used in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

If I insert 'byebug' gem in my Gemfile like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

the gem it's not used:

```
bundle install | grep bye
# Nothing comes out
```

However, if I put the gem outside 'development' looks like it picks it up:

```
bundle install | grep bye
Using byebug 11.1.3
```

What's going on? Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: What Rails environment are you running `bundle install` in? Maybe it’s set to "production".

Comment: Thanks. I tried `RAILS_ENV=development bundle install` but it doesn't change the behavior :-/

Comment: shouldn't it be `platforms`, not `platform`? (plural, not singular)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov that's not the case I tested locally and mine working with the singular

Comment: Looks like ruby and bundler versions may play a role, tested with 2.6.6 + bundler 2.1.4 and your first method works ok